# Auth0 Calling API

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, auth0

Can somebody help to understand the following code snippet from Auth0 API quick start

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://polarcrm.auth0.com/oauth/token \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{"client_id":"7Sxxxxxxx","client_secret":"J-_Xxxf5gS0lHQnxxxxxx","audience":"https://api.polarcrm.com","grant_type":"client_credentials"}'
```

Making the call above is successful and it provides me with an Access_Token
Using that token I can make calls to API, it all works fine.

But it does not make sense to me at all. 
I have a user who is authenticated on my SPA application. Auth0 already knows who is the user and have all user information, including his access token and id_token.
But now when that user makes a call to API, the API knows nothing about the user. The access token generated in the above snippet. It has only the following data in the payload:

```
{
  "iss": "https://polarcrm.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "7Sxxxxxx@clients",
  "aud": "https://api.polarcrm.com",
  "iat": 1564769606,
  "exp": 1564856006,
  "azp": "7Sxxxxxx",
  "gty": "client-credentials"
}
```

What is the purpose of that token if my API knows nothing about who calling it. How API can return user-specific data?

How can I pass user information to the API?

When sending different token (from ASP.NET Core authentication) or id_token from SPA (they contains user information) the API call failing with Unauthorized error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using client credentials flow there is no user context. For an SPA use authorization code flow with pkce. This returns a token containing a user id.

It is a little tricky, so if it helps here is what messages look like: https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/

Happy to answer follow up questions if needed ..

Comment: The following article helped a lot. https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vanillajs/02-calling-an-api

Comment: The actual fix for my problem was very simple. I was missing "audience" when creating auth0 client
auth0 = await createAuth0Client({
    domain: config.domain,
    client_id: config.clientId,
    audience: config.audience
  });